# How do I fix PhoneGap build errors?

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova

I am trying to build a [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)-based iPhone application, but I keep getting the following two errors:

```
./build-phonegap.sh: line 6: ./configure: No such file or directory
cp: lib/iphone/phonegap-min.js: No such file or directory
```

I built and installed the latest version of PhoneGap from the source on GitHub. I have checked to make sure that the `PHONEGAPLIB` variable is indeed set in XCode.

Where do I get the files listed? Where do I put them (to what are those paths relative)? And why aren't they already there?

**Later**

It seems the problem was that the project had been created with one version of PhoneGap (one that doesn't reference an external `lib` directory), but I was trying to run it with a newer one. Recreating the project with my latest version and copying over the `www` directory fixed the problem.

Comment: does this file: lib/iphone/phonegap-min.js  exist?

Comment: there is no `lib` directory in my project or in the folder that `PHONEGAPLIB` points to. Where should it be? And where would it come from?

Answer (score 2):

I am confused.  What steps do I take?  I just downloaded phonegap.  I don't know how to "install" it.  Do I have to run some git command or some build command before I can open it in xcode?

UPDATE:

Figured it out.  I downloaded it.  Unzipped it.  Went into the phonegap folder.  Duplicated the iphone folder.  Opened xcode and hit build and go.  It worked.

Apparently your iphone gap projects need to be a subfolder of the phonegap folder.  That can probably be fixed/changed if you know what you're doing.

This video here helped me verify that all you need to do is download, unzip and open.  The files inside your www do work by default.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcES5nIbMkk